# How to remove newline character within a double-quoted column in a tsv file?

Tags: text-processing

I need "THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE" in one row (newline from the column2 and column4 need to remove).

```
"column1"   "column2"          "column3"    "column4"           " column5"
"DATA"       "THIS                 "DATA"   "THIS                "DATA"
             CONTAIN NEWLINE"                 CONTAIN NEWLINE"
```

Expected output:

```
"column1"   "column2"                "column3"  "column4"                " column5"
"DATA"      "THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE"    "DATA"    "THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE"     "DATA"
```

Comment: the number of \t (tab) characters are consistent? for example there is exactly one \t before CONTAIN NEWLINE"?

Comment: It's not clear how you can differentiate between new data line and \n in the first column.

Comment: Yes, in between the data " " will be there.

Comment: if the first column contains a\nb\nc\n how do you know the lines starting with b and c are not separate data lines with missing fields? Or there can be no \n in the first column?

Comment: First column No \n, \n is only the end of the first row. I need to select column2 and eliminate the \n and save the file.

Comment: The textual data you have posted does not match the image, `"column3"` is not right-aligned with `"DATA"` below it, which is it? This is important because my next question would have been whether the alignment of the column headers to the data is always correct? Also, can the fields contain any quotes, escaped or otherwise? Like `" foo "" bar "` or `"foo \" bar "`?

Comment: It's just a text data inside " ", but in some columns, it will be having newline and display in a new row, becoz of this when I am trying to upload into Cassandra db it's considering as a new entity and throwing error I need to remove these new lines.

Comment: Sorry, but the file format is *still* unclear to me. If this really is a "TSV" (Tab-Separated-Values) file, then it seems unlikely the columns in your sample data would look so neatly aligned. Are you *sure* this isn't a format with fixed-width columns (even if those widths are different across different files)? The typical tools for reading / writing files like that in Perl are `unpack` resp. `printf`.

Answer (score 1):

What makes this text-processing issue difficult or unusual is that the columns have to be processed individually.

This is a bit of a hack, but it seems to do the job:

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -f newfile
for column in 1 2 3 4 5; do
        cut -f "$column" file |
        perl -ne 'chomp;$nl = ((tr /"/"/ % 2 == 0) ? "\n" : " "); print $_, $nl' |
        sed -e 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' -e '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d' |
        { if [ -f newfile ]; then
                paste newfile -
          else
                cat
          fi
        } >newfile.tmp
        mv newfile.tmp newfile
done
```

The script assumes that the input file is called `file` and it will create a file called `newfile` (and using the filename `newfile.tmp` for temporary data). It further assumes that the columns are properly tab-delimited.

It extracts the tab-delimited columns, one by one, from the original file with `cut`. Each individual column is passed through a short Perl script:

```
chomp;
$nl = ( ( tr /"/"/ % 2 == 0 ) ? "\n" : " " );
print $_, $nl;
```

This counts the number of double quotes on each line and will output the line with an appended newline if the line contains an even number of double quotes.  If the number of quotation marks is odd, it will instead append a space character at the end of the line (thus merging quoted strings that span lines).  This is a hackish way of doing this.

The `sed` will do some cleanup, removing trailing blank space from the end of lines and deleting empty lines.

I then `paste` this new data as a new tab-delimited column in `newfile` (by first outputting to `newfile.tmp` and then renaming this file).  The `cat` is run only for the very first column when `newfile` does not yet exist.

With the given input data, assuming that the columns are properly tab-delimited, this will produce the following tab-delimited file:

```
"column1"       "column2"       "column3"       "column4"       " column5"
"DATA"  "THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE"  "DATA"  "THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE"  "DATA"
```

With the tabs replaced by pipe-symbols (to show where the columns start and end):

```
$ tr '\t' '|' <newfile
"column1"|"column2"|"column3"|"column4"|" column5"
"DATA"|"THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE"|"DATA"|"THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE"|"DATA"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```bash
~$ raku -e 'my @a = [Z] lines.map(*.split: "\t");                 \
            @a.=map: *.join(" "); @a.=map: *.comb(/\" .+?  \"/);  \ 
            $_.join("\t").put for [Z] @a;'   file
```

*[Nota bene:  the file supplied by the OP more resembles a `groff` outputted table than a `tsv` file. If this was a `tsv` file, the internal `\n` in row2/column2 would push row2 data for columns 3,4,5 to the next line].*

This solution assumes a substantially cleaned-up input file. Table text has been shortened (`"INTERNAL\nNEWLINE"` instead of `"THIS\nCONTAIN NEWLINE"`) to visualize the columns better (the code still works on fields with internal whitespace, however). Finally, the third (overflow) line--containing the 'continuation' of columns 2 and 4--has inserted `""` column placeholders as described generally by the [OP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/435516/how-to-remove-newline-character-within-a-column-in-a-tsv-file#comment786578_435516). This ensures that each column has an entry per row, even if it's an empty string.

Briefly, in the first statement for each `line`, columns are `split` on `\t` tabs, then `[Z]` zip-reduced to transpose rows and columns. The result is assigned to `@a` array. In the second statement, each row (formerly column) is `join`ed together into a single string, reconstituting the formerly 'broken' double-quoted data in columns 2 and 4.

In the third statement,  each row (formerly column) is `comb`ed, i.e. broken ***around*** double-quoted text, returning 2 elements per row. This 5 x 2 row/column array is then again `[Z]` zip-reduced (i.e. transposed) to 2 x 5 row/column array, columns are `join`ed via `\t` tabs, and out`put`.

Sample Input (tab-separated columns):

```
"column1"   "column2"   "column3"   "column4"   "column5"
"DATA1" "INTERNAL   "DATA3" "INTERNAL   "DATA5"
""  NEWLINE"    ""  NEWLINE"    ""
```

Sample Output (tab-separated columns):

```
"column1"   "column2"   "column3"   "column4"   "column5"
"DATA1" "INTERNAL NEWLINE"  "DATA3" "INTERNAL NEWLINE"  "DATA5"
```

There are two simple ways to better visualize the output columns above: the first is to join on `|` pipe characters as @Kusalananda did. Replacing the last `join("\t")` by `join("|")` instead returns the following:

```
"column1"|"column2"|"column3"|"column4"|"column5"
"DATA1"|"INTERNAL NEWLINE"|"DATA3"|"INTERNAL NEWLINE"|"DATA5"
```

The second (and possibly more informative way is to call `.raku` or `.perl` on the output, which gives a 'data-dumper'-like return (i.e. a peek at Raku's internal representation of the data). Thus a last statement consisting of `.raku.put for [Z] @a;` returns the following (note escaped double-quotes):

```
("\"column1\"", "\"column2\"", "\"column3\"", "\"column4\"", "\"column5\"")
("\"DATA1\"", "\"INTERNAL NEWLINE\"", "\"DATA3\"", "\"INTERNAL NEWLINE\"", "\"DATA5\"")
```

https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

```
co=$(awk '/^[[:space:]]/{print $0}' filename |perl -pne 's/"/\n/g' |sed -r -e 's/^\s+//g' -e '/^$/d'|awk '{if(!seen[$0]++)print }')

awk -v co="$co" 'NR==1{print }/DATA/{$2=$2" "co"\"";$4=$4" "co"\"";print $0}' filename
```

output

```
"column1"   "column2"          "column3"    "column4"           " column5"
"DATA" "THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE" "DATA" "THIS CONTAIN NEWLINE" "DATA"
```